# Unable to find crashes in the crashlytics DashBoard

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using fabric Sdk. The twitter works perfectly. Even crashlytics was working properly. But from last 10 days, none of the crashes are reported in crashlytics. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the docs.

Build.gradle of the app:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/repo" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
}
```

build.gradle of the project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

dependencies {

```
 compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

I have also included the meta data in the manifest file. In my application class:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        appInstance = this;

        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new Crashlytics());

        Crashlytics.setBool(CRASHLYTICS_KEY_CRASHES, true);
```

Also, when I checked the log, I'm getting the log as : "Crash report is uploaded to Crashlytics". But its not present in the dashboard.

Is there anything that I have missed. Is anyone else is facing similar issue? thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

try this in buildcript:

```
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

and in your application class, use

```
 Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

instead of `Crashlytics.setBool(CRASHLYTICS_KEY_CRASHES, true);`

Comment: I have included this in buildscript & also I have written    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig), new Crashlytics()); .